# Working with SVG paths in BeautifulSoup & Python

Tags: python, css, svg, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a Python script that will color in various areas of my city's Census Block Groups (of which there are 18) different colors according to their respective median household incomes on a map that's in the SVG format.

Sounds simple enough, right? Well, I can't figure out how, though I'm making slight progress.  What I've tried so far is making a list of each of the block group paths according to how the SVG references them, making a list of the median household incomes, then passing in the code that colors them.  However, this just.. doesn't seem to be working, for whatever reason.  Can any of you wonderful people help figure out where I'm misfiring?

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

icbg = []
reader = csv.reader(open('censusdata.csv'),delimiter=",")

#read and get income
for row in reader:
   income = row[6]
   income = int(income)
   icbg.append(income)

svg = open('NM2.svg','r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(svg,"lxml")

#find CBGs and incomes
path1 = soup.find('path')
path2 = path1.find_next('path')
path3 = path2.find_next('path')
path4 = path3.find_next('path')
path5 = path4.find_next('path')
path6 = path5.find_next('path')
path7 = path6.find_next('path')
path8 = path7.find_next('path')
path9 = path8.find_next('path')
path10 = path9.find_next('path')
path11 = path10.find_next('path')
path12 = path11.find_next('path')
path13 = path12.find_next('path')
path14 = path13.find_next('path')
path15 = path14.find_next('path')
path16 = path15.find_next('path')
path17 = path16.find_next('path')
path18 = path17.find_next('path')
incomep1 = icbg[0]
incomep2 = icbg[1]
incomep3 = icbg[2]
incomep4 = icbg[3]
incomep5 = icbg[4]
incomep6 = icbg[5]
incomep7 = icbg[6]
incomep8 = icbg[7]
incomep9 = icbg[8]
incomep10 = icbg[9]
incomep11 = icbg[10]
incomep12 = icbg[11]
incomep13 = icbg[12]
incomep14 = icbg[13]
incomep15 = icbg[14]
incomep16 = icbg[15]
incomep17 = icbg[16]
incomep18 = icbg[17]

paths = (path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7, path8, path9, path10,
             path11, path12, path13, path14, path15, path16, path17, path18)
incomes = (incomep1,incomep2,incomep3,incomep4,incomep5,incomep6,incomep7,incomep8,
               incomep9,incomep10,incomep11,incomep12,incomep13,incomep14,incomep15,incomep16,incomep17,incomep18)

#set colors
colors = ['fee5d9','fcae91','fb6a4a','de2d26','a50f15']

for p in paths:
    for i in range(0,17):
        it = incomes[i]
        if it > 20000:
            color_class = 2
        elif it > 25000:
            color_class = 1
        elif it > 30000:
            color_class = 3
        elif it > 35000:
            color_class = 4

        color = colors[color_class]
        path_style = "font-size:12px;fill:#%s;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel" % color
        p['style'] = path_style
    print(soup.prettify())
```

Running this gives me an SVG file like so: `fill:#fb6a4a;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel">` comes up 18 times, meaning for every available path, even though these paths have different incomes.

could the problem be with the way I wrote my comparisons?

Comment: Please use lists to store your paths and incomes from the start! Something like this should work:

`paths[0] = soup.find('path')`
`for x in range(1, 18): paths[x] = paths[x-1].find_next('path')`
`incomes = [icbg[x] for x in range(18)]`

Comment: thank you @ErikJohnson, I knew there was a far more pythonic way of accomplishing that.. mucho gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of what you are trying to do, your problem is that you have 2 `for` loops instead of one. You should loop through the paths and incomes at the same time.  The way you are doing it now is you are looping through all the incomes for each path.  The following code simply moves the paths into the same loop as the income so they are looped through at the same time.

```
for i in range(0,17):
    it = incomes[i]
    p = paths[i]
    if it > 20000:
        color_class = 2
    elif it > 25000:
        color_class = 1
    elif it > 30000:
        color_class = 3
    elif it > 35000:
        color_class = 4

    color = colors[color_class]
    path_style = "font-size:12px;fill:#%s;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel" % color
    p['style'] = path_style
```